# find all positive integers n for which there exists a certain $n\times n$ table where each entry is I,M, or O

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> Find all positive integers $n$ for which we can fill in the entries of an $n\times n$ table with the following properties:

- Each entry can be one of $I,M,O$;
- In each row and each column, the letters $I,M,O$ occur the same number of times;
- In any diagonal whose number of entries is a multiple of three, the letters $I,M,O$ occur the same number of times.

> 

The following matrix seems to work for $n=9$ :

```
I I I M M M O O O
M M M O O O I I I
O O O I I I M M M
I I I M M M O O O
M M M O O O I I I
O O O I I I M M M
I I I M M M O O O
M M M O O O I I I
O O O I I I M M M
```

I also think one can extend this matrix for any n that's a multiple of 9, say $n=9k$, in the natural way. That is, for each of the $k^2$ $9\times 9$ submatrices of the original matrix, fill it with the entries of the given 9 by 9 matrix. However, I'm not sure how to (formally) prove that this construction works. Obviously each entry is one of I,M,O and in each row and column the letters I,M,O occur the same number of times. But how can I prove the last condition is satisfied? Also, I think n must be a multiple of 9.

Comment: In any $9k \times 9k$ grid made up of copies of the matrix given, any diagonal with $3m$ entries must be the concatenation of some number of diagonals with $3n$ entries in the original matrix. The entries in a NW--SE diagonal must begin (starting at the topmost entry) with two indices of $1 \pmod 3$ and end with two of $0 \pmod 3$; a NE-SW diagonal has the opposite properties. So when the diagonal "crosses" from one submatrix to another, the indices are forced to connect to a similar diagonal. Is that enough to work from?

Comment: (Note this doesn't preclude a $12 \times 12$ grid, for instance, from existing; that you'd have to prove separately.)

Comment: This is an IMO problem, IMO.